# Ошибка подключения к БД "The underlying provider failed on Open"

Tags: sql

У меня есть приложение-словарь, которое я написал на своём PC.
Я запустил его на ноутбуке и всё отлично работает, я добавлял слова в БД.

После этого я копирую файлы mdf и ldf на свой PC.
Хочу запустить своё приложение и получаю ошибку:
The underlying provider failed on Open
Подскажите, пожалуйста, из-за чего она происходит ? И как её побороть ?

Comment: Скорее всего, дело в правах. Сервис MS SQL работает под каким-то аккаунтом -- этот юзер не имеет прав на скопированные вами файлы.

Comment: А как это исправить ?

Comment: В Проводнике открыть папку где эти файлы лежат, правой кнопкой на файл, свойства, права, изменить -- например дать права пользователю Everyone.

Answer (score 1):

Не рекомендуется переносить базы данных SQL Server в виде файлов mdf и ldf. Еще хуже - копировать их с работающего SQL Server'а.

Предпочтительный вариант - сделать бэкап на одном компьютере и потом восстановить его на другом.

Если все же хотите переносить файлами, вам стоит придерживаться такой последовательности:

1. Отключите базу данных на машине, с которой копируете файлы. Если просто копируете - достаточно перевести базу в OFFLINE, если переносите - делаете отключение базы (detach).
2. Переносите файлы
3. На машине, куда переносите, делаете подключение базы данных (attach).

При этом надо учитывать, что версия и выпуск SQL Server должна быть не ниже той, с которой файлы скопированы, если мажорная версия будет ниже, база не подключится точно, если выпуск будет ниже - не подключится, если в базе есть объекты, доступные только в более старшем выпуске.